# Javascript Integer increment does not work unless called from function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was going to post this as a question to a problem but i later found a 'solution' (if that is what it is) and now this is more like an attempt to understand the situation.

I have a javascript code that displays the number `0` on the screen and then when a button is clicked, the number is supposed to increase according to the amount of times the button is clicked.

[image]

This was the code i used initially:

```
var number = 0;

$ (document).ready (function() {

    document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "Number of clicks: " + number;
    $("#submit").bind ('click', function(event) {
    document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "Number of clicks: " + number++;

});
});
```

Problem was the button click event only worked AFTER the second click.Meaning i had to click the button twice before the incrementation worked.
So i created a function:

```
function increment () {
   number++;
   return number;
}
```

and then changed the last line of the initial code to:

```
   document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "Number of clicks: " + increment();
```

Now the number increases the first time i click on the button.
I just need to know why the first method didn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use ++number instead of number++

number++ increases the value of number afterwards.

Comment: Oh i see, it worked.This explains some of my other nightmares.

Comment: This answer gives you the solution but does not explain @Ojonugwa Ochalifu.

Comment: You are kinda right, it answers the first part of the question but not why the incrementation works fine when called from a function.

Comment: @OjonugwaOchalifu In your function, the variable is being returned *after* being incremented.

Answer (score 3):

You code is running fine, even in the first time. But the value displayed is`1` less than the number of the clicks.

You are using `prefix increment operator (++counter)`. In `prefix increment operation` first the value is `evaluated or returned` and then `incremented`.

But in `postfix increment operation (counter++)` first the value will be `incremented` and then `returned`

Use the existing code and initialize the `number` as `1` and execute the code.

You will get the expected result.

Should you want to maintain the initialization as `0`, use `postfix increment operator` to get the desired result.

My recommendation would be not to use either of them but the below one

```
number += 1;
```

Comment: You got that backwards, but  +1 for remembering the terminology I couldn't - postfix vs prefix increment.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty common in a lot of languages.

```
var i = 0; 
1 + i++
```

returns 1

```
var i = 0; 
1 + ++i
```

returns 2

The difference is whether the variable is incremented before or after being evaluated in the expression.

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
$('#target').click(function() {
    $('#output').html(function(i, val) { return val*1+1 });
});
```

HTML is

```
<button id="target" type="button">Click Me</button>
<div id="output">10</div>
```

[SEE DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/nMEuL/)

Answer (score 1):

```
 The answer is simple, why your first code did not work for you, as expected.

 var number = 0;

 $ (document).ready (function() {

   document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "Number of clicks: " + number;
    $("#submit").bind ('click', function(event) {
     document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "Number of clicks: " + number++;

    });
 });

 >>> This first time when DOM element load, The Value get printed as :
     output : Number of clicks: 0 // because you have initialize number as 0.
     Now when you click "Click Button", you have POST-INCREMENTED the Value, means 
     the value get's incremented after the action is completed. So in this case,
     when you click first time, the number is still 0 and get printed again as
    "Number of clicks": 0 and then the value get's incremented by Post-increment
    and become's 1. When you click for second time,
    the output :"Number of click": 1 get's printed.
```